# Any known strategies for toads and frogs?

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Are there any heuristic strategic for playing [Toads and Frogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toads_and_Frogs_%28game%29) known? I reckon the optimal playthrough may be hard to achieve due to the game being NP-hard but at least something that regularly performs better than a random approach. All I could find were papers on evaluating some positions and scientific look at the said matter - I'm not interested in anything provably optimal, being (abstractly speaking) "rather good" is suitable for me :)

Comment: Even though this would seem to be a more appropriate place to ask the question, everything I would have brought up (and more) has been brought up at your version of this question at http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12471/finding-a-winning-strategy-for-toads-and-frogs